# Excepción al iniciar el cliente: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

Tengo un servidor y un cliente. Cuando inicio el servidor me sale en la pantalla:

> compile-single:
>   run-single:

Pero cuando le doy a iniciar el cliente me da error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>       at ioc.dam.m9.uf3.eac2.b2.Alumne.main(clienteUDP.java:42)
>
> C:\Users\Montse\Desktop\8 TRIMESTRE\M09  - Programacio de serveis i processos\EAC2\M09_EAC2_Enunciat_1718S2\EAC2_Enunciat\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1051: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Users\Montse\Desktop\8 TRIMESTRE\M09  - Programacio de serveis i processos\EAC2\M09_EAC2_Enunciat_1718S2\EAC2_Enunciat\nbproject\build-impl.xml:805: Java returned: 1
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Es decir para iniciarlos voy encima y botón derecho Run File. ¿Hay que hacerlo de otra forma?

El código debería de estar bien. No sé si es falta de información por mi parte o es por que los ejecuto mal. ¿Podéis ayudarme?

El código del programa son los siguientes:

**Servidor**

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class ServidorUDP {

      public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

            byte[] bufer = new byte[1024];//bufer para recibir el datagrama

            //ASOCIO EL SOCKET AL PUERTO 12345
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(12345);

            //ESPERANDO DATAGRAMA
            System.out.println("Esperando Datagrama ................");
            DatagramPacket recibo = new DatagramPacket(bufer, bufer.length);
            socket.receive(recibo);//recibo datagrama
            int bytesRec = recibo.getLength();//obtengo numero de bytes   
            String paquete= new String(recibo.getData());//obtengo String

            //VISUALIZO INFORMACIÓN
            System.out.println("Número de Bytes recibidos: " + bytesRec);
            System.out.println("Contenido del Paquete    : " + paquete.trim());
            System.out.println("Puerto origen del mensaje: " + recibo.getPort());
            System.out.println("IP de origen             : " + recibo.getAddress().getHostAddress());
            System.out.println("Puerto destino del mensaje:" + socket.getLocalPort());

            socket.close(); //cierro el socket

      }//Fin de main

}// Fin de SerivdorUDP
```

**Cliente**

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class ClienteUDP {

      public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

            InetAddress destino = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            int port = 12345; //puerto al que envío el datagrama
            byte[] mensaje = new byte[1024];

            String Saludo="Enviando Saludos !!";
            mensaje = Saludo.getBytes(); //codifico String a bytes

            //CONSTRUYO EL DATAGRAMA A ENVIAR
            DatagramPacket envio = new DatagramPacket (mensaje, mensaje.length, destino, port);
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(34567);//Puerto local
            System.out.println("Enviando Datagrama de longitud: "+ mensaje.length);
            System.out.println("Host destino : "+ destino.getHostName());
            System.out.println("IP Destino : " + destino.getHostAddress());
            System.out.println("Puerto local del socket: " + socket.getLocalPort());
            System.out.println("Puerto al que envio: " + envio.getPort());

            //ENVIO DATAGRAMA
            socket.send(envio);
            socket.close(); //cierro el socket

      }//Fin de main

}//Fin de ClienteUDP
```

---

Al final la solución fue actualizar el JDK.

Probé varios ejemplos y en todos el servidor funcionaba pero el cliente saltaba error.

Fue actualizarlo y conseguí que ya funcionara.

Comment: ¿Qué IDE usas? El error no parece estar en el código

Comment: La excepción ocurre porque estás intentando acceder a una posición del array que no es válida (porque el índice usado es negativo o es mayor que el tamaño del array). ¿Cuál es la línea 42 de clienteUDP.java?

Comment: @PabloLozano uso netbeans

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro he probado otros programas de libros y me dan error también. así que tiene que ser algo relacionado con Netbeans o que no sé encenderlos o que me falta algo.. no del código.. :(

Comment: No puedo saber si los otros errores son por la plataforma o por el código, pero esta excepción en concreto ocurre por algo en el código, y según el mensaje, en la línea 42 de clienteUDP.java.

Comment: Si crees que es un problema de NetBeans y es general con todos los programas que tienes: desinstala NetBeans y vuelve a instalarlo. Después vuelve a probar el código y comprueba si funciona o no, y edita la pregunta para actualizar los resultados/problemas.

Comment: sigue igual... ya lo he probado el servidor se enciende pero se queda pendiente.

Comment: Que otro editor puedo usar que sea parecido? :

Comment: ¿El código que has puesto en la pregunta es el contenido completo de clienteUDP? ¿A qué te refieres con que "_el servidor se enciende pero se queda pendiente_"?

Comment: Es decir primero le doy run file a SERVIDOR.UDP y luego le doy a run File a ClienteUDP. El error me lo da cuando le doy a run file clienteUDP. Estoy haciendo algo incorrecto?

Comment: y si es el contenido completo.

Comment: Entiendo que el servidor se queda pendiente de iniciar el cliente no?

Comment: Es posible que al ejecutar el programa no estés ejecutadolo realmente: el error dice *Alumne.main(clienteUDP.java:42)* (la clase empieza con minúscula). Mira si hay otros archivos de otro alumno

Comment: lo pruebo al llegar a casa y te digo.

Comment: ya lo he conseguido tenia que instalar el JDK.. ha sido actualizarlo y ya me ha funcionado.. :S

Comment: @MontseMkd si el problema era que no tenías instalado el JDK (o no era la versión correcta), deberías poner una respuesta con eso y aceptarla pasado el tiempo necesario. Sin tratar de quitar mérito a la respuesta de ivan fajardo, has aceptado como correcta una respuesta que no tiene nada que ver con la solución que acabaste implementando. Eso no sirve de ayuda a otros usuarios y no es bueno para el sitio. Te recomiendo leer [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](/help/someone-answers) y [answer].

Answer (score 1):

En el cliente no deberías hacer bind socket a ningún puerto. Para enviar mensajes desde el cliente al servidor el codigo seria algo asi:

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();

byte[] buffer = "Enviando Saludos !!".getBytes();
InetAddress destino = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
DatagramPacket mensaje= new DatagramPacket( buffer, buffer.length,receiverAddress, 12345);
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
socket.send(mensaje);
```